# Help identifying this mint-like plant

Tags: identification

I'd like some help identifying a mint-like plant, and was wondering if I could use it in cooking.

I've had a garden for a few years now, and every year a mint-like plant has popped up.
I call it mint-like because of it's very minty smell, and grows similar to the 'regular' mint I know. The leaves are kind of small and fuzzy. Around june/july the plant will have light pink flowers. At the end of the year they usually wilt away to come back next spring. If it's relevant, I live in west europe.

After looking around my best guess would be that it's apple mint (Mentha suaveolens).

Below is a photo taken last week.

[image: Photo of the plant]

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia agrees with you, *suaveolens*, a culinary and medicinal herb with a spearminty flavor. Use in tea, tomato soup, zucchini, pesto, chick/fish/meats, and brownies.